# how to disable the flashing notification in office communicator (work group instant message)?

Tags: office-communicator

At work I get constant flashes on the group instant message I'm in and it's very annoying Is there a way to disable the flashing notification when someone types something in the group?

I've gone thru settings and disabled as many notifications as i can, but the flash still appears in the task bar after someone adds something to the window.

I'm currently using office communicator 2007.

Comment: If anyone has some input to help stop that dumb flashing, short of changing the code in the program, id be ever appreciative!!!

Comment: Great question... anyone?